# Get count of each distinct word from array of strings

Tags: c#, linq

I have array of strings:

```
string[] arrStr = {"I am from USA","I like stackoverflow","stackoverflow always helps"};
```

I want to get count of each word from all the strings like

```
I : 2                 
stackoverflow : 2              
from : 1
```

I want to get this result using LINQ and only using one statement

Comment: What about sentences like "I am Ravi. I like computers"? Would you have this? Would you exclude the period? How about other punctuation such as question marks?

Comment: *I want* (twice). I assume you're not ordering source code here. So, you tried, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
  string[] words =string.Join(" ",arrStr).Split(' ').ToArray();

        var groups =
            from w in words
            group w by w into g
                select new
                {
                 Count=g.Count(), 
                 Word=g.Key
                };
```

It will give you a collection of objects like:

Count: 2
Word: stackoverflow

Count: 1
Word: from

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a group by and also using `SelectMany` to flatten all the words first:

```
var result= array.SelectMany(s=>s.Split(' '))
                 .GroupBy(s=>s)
                 .Select(g=>new {Word= g.Key,Count=g.Count()});
```